# Infinite While Loop in a construction heurstic JAVA

Tags: java

I'm working on a metaheuristic and I'm currently stuck in my construction heuristic.

I have a set of lectures of courses (each course is a custom object Course with a few properties of that course) that need to be put in rooms a time table/schedule and each of them has an index on how restricted it is.

My program starts by sorting the courses based on the highest index and then splits them into two Arraylists of high-priority courses and non-priority courses. The program then takes the high priority first, randomizes a course, and does:

while there are still courses in the ArrayList

while the course still has lectures that were unscheduled (lect>0)

```
  randomize a day and a room

  go through the periods of that day

  evaluate if the course can be placed in that period - day

  evaluate if the room on that period day is available

  if yes place a lecture there and decrement the number of lectures (lect--)

  if not go to the next period

  if you don't find a period on that day & room, randomize a new day & room and do the process over
  again
```

When all the lectures are done exit

If the course cannot be placed anywhere anymore then I enter an infinite loop in the while (lect>0) and my program does not run beyond that. How can I fix this?

I was thinking of doing a count=MaxCount and decrement at the end of each while iteration that does not place a lecture and say IF(count==0) break the while. When I evaluate the period/day I need to decrement by the number of rooms while if I evaluate the room I need to decrement by 1, but then for some reason my count always gets to negative and when I say check IF(count<=0) I have a lot of courses left out.

```
ArrayList<Course> ALC = sortCourses();
        ArrayList<Course> ALCP = new ArrayList<Course>();

        float mean = meanCourseIndex();

        while(ALC.get(0).getCourseIndex()>=mean){
            ALCP.add(ALC.get(0));
            ALC.remove(0);
        }

        //Now, ALC refers to the non-priority courses

        //Choosing a random priority course to place
        while(!ALCP.isEmpty()){
            //Randomize the course chosen
            int rand =  (int) (Math.random()*ALCP.size());
            int lect = ALCP.get(rand).getNumLectures();
            int a = 0;
            while(a!=1){
                int countMax = (rooms.length*numPeriods*numDays);
                while(lect>0){
                        Random randD = new Random();
                        int randDay = randD.nextInt(numDays);
                        int randRoom = pickRandomRoomIndex();
                        outerloop:
                        for (int j=0; j<numPeriods; j++){
                            // Check course availability in the slot
                            if(slotAvailability(ALCP.get(rand),randDay,j)==true){
                                //place the course in the random room
                                if(rooms[randRoom].getRoomSchedule()[j][randDay].equals("AV")){
                                   rooms[randRoom].getRoomSchedule()[j][randDay]= ALCP.get(rand).getCourseID();

                                   //Set the lecturer of the course for that time slot to be unavailable
                                   for(int i=0; i<lecturers.length; i++){
                                       if(lecturers[i].getLecturerID().equals(ALCP.get(rand).getCourseLecturer())){
                                           lecturers[i].getLecturerAvailability()[j][randDay]=true;
                                           break;
                                       }
                                   }
                                   //Set the curriculum of the course for that time slot to be unavailable
                                   for(int i=0; i<ALCP.get(rand).getCourseCurriculum().size(); i++){
                                       for(int k=0; k<curriculum.length; k++){
                                           if(curriculum[k].getCurriculaID().equals(ALCP.get(rand).getCourseCurriculum().get(i))){
                                               curriculum[k].getCurAvailability()[j][randDay]=true;
                                               break;
                                           }
                                       }
                                   }
                                    lect-=1;
                                   break outerloop;
                                } else {
                                    countMax = countMax - 1;
                                }
                            } else {
                                countMax = countMax - rooms.length;
                            }
                        }
                        if(countMax<=0){
                            lect=0;
                        }
                }
                a=1;
            }
            ALCP.remove(rand);
        }
```

Comment: It does not make tooooo much sense (I overread but it's kind of heavy). Try showing some relevant code maybe ?

Comment: Show us some code, especially the main while loop with the core logic.

Comment: I added the code for the part I'm describing above. Hope it makes more sense!

Comment: first thing I notice, the almost outer loop

`a = 0;
while (a != 1){
  // some shit I didn't read
  a = 1;
}
`
seems to be easily replaced by :

`// some shit I didn't read`

I would advise cleaning / simplifying your code where you can, it needs some breathing I think